# Symfony2 Doctrine2 - generate One-To-Many annotation from existing database by doctrine:mapping:import

Tags: php, database, symfony, orm, doctrine-orm

I want to  generate Entities from an Existing Database by using Doctrine tools for reverse engineering

```
/*
 * SET FOREIGN_KEY_CHECKS=0;
  -- ----------------------------
  -- Table structure for `country`
  -- ----------------------------
  DROP TABLE IF EXISTS `country`;
  CREATE TABLE `country` (
  `id` int(11) unsigned NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
  `name` varchar(255) NOT NULL DEFAULT '',
  PRIMARY KEY (`id`)
  ) ENGINE=InnoDB AUTO_INCREMENT=38 DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8;


  -- ----------------------------
  -- Table structure for `provider`
  -- ----------------------------
  DROP TABLE IF EXISTS `provider`;
  CREATE TABLE `provider` (
  `id` int(11) unsigned NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
  `name` varchar(255) NOT NULL DEFAULT '',
  PRIMARY KEY (`id`)
  ) ENGINE=InnoDB AUTO_INCREMENT=13 DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8;

  -- ----------------------------
  -- Table structure for `provider_country`
  -- ----------------------------
  DROP TABLE IF EXISTS `provider_country`;
  CREATE TABLE `provider_country` (
  `id` int(11) unsigned NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
  `providerId` int(11) unsigned NOT NULL,
  `countryId` int(11) unsigned NOT NULL,
  PRIMARY KEY (`id`),
  KEY `fk_provider_has_id0_idx` (`providerId`),
  KEY `fk_user_country_idx` (`countryId`),
  CONSTRAINT `fk_rss_has_id` FOREIGN KEY (`providerId`) REFERENCES `provider` (`id`) ON DELETE NO ACTION ON UPDATE NO ACTION,
  CONSTRAINT `fk_user_country` FOREIGN KEY (`countryId`) REFERENCES `country` (`id`) ON DELETE NO ACTION ON UPDATE NO ACTION
  ) ENGINE=InnoDB AUTO_INCREMENT=8 DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8;

  SET FOREIGN_KEY_CHECKS=1;
 */
```

you can ask Doctrine to import the schema and build related entity classes by executing the following two commands.

1 $ `php app/console doctrine:mapping:import AcmeBlogBundle annotation`
  2 $ `php app/console doctrine:generate:entities AcmeBlogBundle`

but now the doctrine detect only ManyToOne relation in many side only "ProviderCountry" table

if i need to add the OneToMany relation i have to add the annotation by my hand by adding the follwing annotation

in Provider.php add

```
/**
 * @ORM\OneToMany(targetEntity="ProviderCountry", mappedBy="providerId", cascade={"persist"})
 */
private $datas;
```

in ProviderCountry.php add

```
    /**
     * @var Provider
     *
     * @ORM\ManyToOne(targetEntity="Provider", inversedBy = "datas")
     * @ORM\JoinColumn(name="providerId", referencedColumnName="id")
     */

private $userid;
```

so how can I genrate One-To-Many annotation by doctrine command

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Simply this is change inside doctrine orm lib,

you can fix that by changes in

vendor/doctrine/orm/lib/Doctrine/ORM/Mapping/Driver/DatabaseDriver.php

replace the following statements

```
foreach ($foreignKeys as $foreignKey) {
          $foreignTable = $foreignKey->getForeignTableName();
          $cols = $foreignKey->getColumns();
          $fkCols = $foreignKey->getForeignColumns();

          $localColumn = current($cols);
          $associationMapping = array();
          $associationMapping['fieldName'] = $this->getFieldNameForColumn($tableName, $localColumn, true);
          $associationMapping['targetEntity'] = $this->getClassNameForTable($foreignTable);

          if ($primaryKeyColumns && in_array($localColumn, $primaryKeyColumns)) {
          $associationMapping['id'] = true;
          }

          for ($i = 0; $i < count($cols); $i++) {
          $associationMapping['joinColumns'][] = array(
          'name' => $cols[$i],
          'referencedColumnName' => $fkCols[$i],
          );
          }

          //Here we need to check if $cols are the same as $primaryKeyColums
          if (!array_diff($cols, $primaryKeyColumns)) {
          $metadata->mapOneToOne($associationMapping);
          } else {
          $metadata->mapManyToOne($associationMapping);
          }
          }
```

change to

```
foreach ($foreignKeys as $foreignKey) {
            $foreignTable = $foreignKey->getForeignTableName();
            $cols = $foreignKey->getColumns();
            $fkCols = $foreignKey->getForeignColumns();

            $localColumn = current($cols);
            $associationMapping = array();
            $associationMapping['fieldName'] = $this->getFieldNameForColumn($tableName, $localColumn, true);
            $associationMapping['targetEntity'] = $this->getClassNameForTable($foreignTable);

            for ($i = 0; $i < count($cols); $i++) {
                $associationMapping['joinColumns'][] = array(
                    'name' => $cols[$i],
                    'referencedColumnName' => $fkCols[$i],
                );
            }
            $metadata->mapManyToOne($associationMapping);
        }

        foreach ($this->tables as $tableCandidate) {
            if ($this->_sm->getDatabasePlatform()->supportsForeignKeyConstraints()) {
                $foreignKeysCandidate = $tableCandidate->getForeignKeys();
            } else {
                $foreignKeysCandidate = array();
            }

            foreach ($foreignKeysCandidate as $foreignKey) {
                $foreignTable = $foreignKey->getForeignTableName();

                if ($foreignTable == $tableName && !isset($this->manyToManyTables[$tableCandidate->getName()])) {

                    $fkCols = $foreignKey->getForeignColumns();
                    $cols = $foreignKey->getColumns();


                    $localColumn = current($cols);

                    $associationMapping = array();
                    $associationMapping['fieldName'] = $this->getFieldNameForColumn($tableCandidate->getName(), $tableCandidate->getName(), true);
                    $associationMapping['targetEntity'] = $this->getClassNameForTable($tableCandidate->getName());
                    $associationMapping['mappedBy'] = $this->getFieldNameForColumn($tableCandidate->getName(), $localColumn, true);

                    try {
                        $primaryKeyColumns = $tableCandidate->getPrimaryKey()->getColumns();
                        if (count($primaryKeyColumns) == 1) {
                            $indexColumn = current($primaryKeyColumns);
                            $associationMapping['indexBy'] = $indexColumn;
                        }
                    } catch (SchemaException $e) {

                    }

                    $metadata->mapOneToMany($associationMapping);
                }
            }
        }
```

now if you run doctrine:mapping:import

you will find OneToMany annotation.

then run  doctrine:generate:entities

you will find A unidirectional relationship on both sides.