# how to generate one to many entity for this table use doctrine generator

Tags: php, sql, doctrine

```
DROP TABLE IF EXISTS `address`;
CREATE TABLE `address` (
  `id` int(11) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
  `customer_id` int(11) DEFAULT NULL,
  `region_code` varchar(255)  DEFAULT NULL,
  `district` varchar(255)  NOT NULL,
  `address` varchar(255)  NOT NULL,
  `created_at` datetime NOT NULL,
  `updated_at` datetime DEFAULT NULL ON UPDATE NOW(),
  PRIMARY KEY (`id`),
  KEY `IDX_B97FF0589395C3F3` (`customer_id`),
  CONSTRAINT `FK_B97FF0589395C3F3` FOREIGN KEY (`customer_id`) REFERENCES    `customer` (`id`) ON DELETE SET NULL
) ENGINE=InnoDB AUTO_INCREMENT=91 DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8;

DROP TABLE IF EXISTS `customer`;
CREATE TABLE `customer` (
  `id` int(11) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
  `shipping_address_id` int(11) DEFAULT NULL,
  `email` varchar(255)  NOT NULL,
  `mobile` varchar(255)  DEFAULT NULL,
  `name` varchar(255)  DEFAULT NULL,
  `birthday` datetime DEFAULT NULL,
  `gender` varchar(1)  NOT NULL DEFAULT 'u',
  `created_at` datetime NOT NULL,
  `updated_at` datetime DEFAULT NULL ON UPDATE NOW(),
  PRIMARY KEY (`id`),
  UNIQUE KEY `UNIQ_7E82D5E64D4CFF2B` (`address_id`),
  CONSTRAINT `FK_7E82D5E64D4CFF2B` FOREIGN KEY (`shipping_address_id`) REFERENCES    `address` (`id`) ON DELETE SET NULL
) ENGINE=InnoDB AUTO_INCREMENT=58 DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8;
```

one customer has a default shipping address, and one address connect to a customer.

Fatal error: Uncaught exception 'Doctrine\ORM\Mapping\MappingException' with message 'Property "customer" in "App\Model\Address" was already declared, but it mu
st be declared only once' in D:\wamp64\www\app\vendor\doctrine\orm\lib\Doctrine\ORM\Mapping\MappingException.php on line 381

Doctrine\ORM\Mapping\MappingException: Property "customer" in "App\Model\Address" was already declared, but it must be declared only once in D:\wamp64\www\app\v
endor\doctrine\orm\lib\Doctrine\ORM\Mapping\MappingException.php on line 381

```
Call Stack:
    0.0010     276728   1. {main}() D:\wamp64\www\app\entities_generator.php:0
    0.9090    9239824   2. Doctrine\Common\Persistence\Mapping\AbstractClassMetadataFactory->getAllMetadata() D:\wamp64\www\app\entities_generator.php:166
    0.9090    9249648   3. Doctrine\Common\Persistence\Mapping\AbstractClassMetadataFactory->getMetadataFor() D:\wamp64\www\app\vendor\doctrine\common\lib\Doctr
ine\Common\Persistence\Mapping\AbstractClassMetadataFactory.php:115
    0.9120    9269408   4. Doctrine\ORM\Mapping\ClassMetadataFactory->loadMetadata() D:\wamp64\www\app\vendor\doctrine\common\lib\Doctrine\Common\Persistence\Ma
pping\AbstractClassMetadataFactory.php:225
    0.9120    9269680   5. Doctrine\Common\Persistence\Mapping\AbstractClassMetadataFactory->loadMetadata() D:\wamp64\www\app\vendor\doctrine\orm\lib\Doctrine\O
RM\Mapping\ClassMetadataFactory.php:78
    0.9260   10011288   6. Doctrine\ORM\Mapping\ClassMetadataFactory->doLoadMetadata() D:\wamp64\www\app\vendor\doctrine\common\lib\Doctrine\Common\Persistence\
Mapping\AbstractClassMetadataFactory.php:332
    0.9260   10011968   7. Doctrine\ORM\Mapping\Driver\DatabaseDriver->loadMetadataForClass() D:\wamp64\www\app\vendor\doctrine\orm\lib\Doctrine\ORM\Mapping\Cla
ssMetadataFactory.php:151
    0.9280   10024816   8. Doctrine\ORM\Mapping\Driver\DatabaseDriver->buildToOneAssociationMappings() D:\wamp64\www\app\vendor\doctrine\orm\lib\Doctrine\ORM\Ma
pping\Driver\DatabaseDriver.php:188
    0.9280   10034064   9. Doctrine\ORM\Mapping\ClassMetadataInfo->mapOneToMany() D:\wamp64\www\app\vendor\doctrine\orm\lib\Doctrine\ORM\Mapping\Driver\Database
Driver.php:535
    0.9280   10036640  10. Doctrine\ORM\Mapping\ClassMetadataInfo->_storeAssociationMapping() D:\wamp64\www\app\vendor\doctrine\orm\lib\Doctrine\ORM\Mapping\Cla
ssMetadataInfo.php:2568
    0.9280   10036640  11. Doctrine\ORM\Mapping\ClassMetadataInfo->assertFieldNotMapped() D:\wamp64\www\app\vendor\doctrine\orm\lib\Doctrine\ORM\Mapping\ClassMe
tadataInfo.php:2617
```

have any idea about this? or can you tell me how to design it to make it more clearly.

thanks advance.

Comment: i have used the change in this link, but it didn't work.
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15474121/symfony2-doctrine2-generate-one-to-many-annotation-from-existing-database-by-d